# RedditSdk full size image is unavailable

Tags: image, reddit, redditkit

I am using https://github.com/samsymons/RedditKit SDK for reddit api's. I have implemented the whole functionality.

I am facing issue in getting full size image from this sdk.

If anybody used this SDK, can help me getting full size image?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full Size is available in RedditSDK.

Just try digging into the picture structure.

Comment: Ok. I will try to find it.
Thanks

Comment: You can ask anything whenever you will do this.